# How can some output of `cat` change how unicode characters are interpreted in bash?

Tags: bash, unicode

This is a question out of sheer curiosity:

I have a custom PS1 setting in bash that is just the current directory, followed by a lowercase lambda (`λ`), e.g. `~λ`. I accidentally used `cat` with a binary file, cancelled the output, and subsequently had the `λ` turn into two Japanese characters `ﾎｻ` for the rest of the session. When pasting in this character from somewhere else, it was also displayed as these two Japanese characters.

Now my question is, how did the output of this binary file change how bash interprets Unicode characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> my question is, how did the output of this binary file change how bash interprets Unicode characters?

Standard Unix terminals support [ANSI/VT-100 commands](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) which can control the cursors, the colors, and the fonts.  When you type an binary file to the screen, it is likely that some of the binary characters will accidentally match such control codes and set properties of your terminal.

To return your terminal to its default state, run:

```
reset
```

#### Examples of VT-100 control sequences

If you would like the text on your teminal to blink, type:

```
echo -e '\E[5m'
```

If you want to switch the display to reverse video, type:

```
echo -e '\E[7m'
```

As a more complex example, consider the `make` command which can produce a lot of output.  To make it easier to spot the important things, you may want to highlight `ERR` in reverse video while displaying `WARNING` in bold.  The [following code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Example_of_use_in_shell_scripting) adds VT-100 controls sequences in to the output of `make` to obtain this highlighting on the terminal:

```
make 2>&1 | sed -e 's/.*\bERR.*/\x1b[7m&\x1b[0m/i' -e 's/.*\bWARN.*/\x1b[1m&\x1b[0m/i'
```

The above adds control sequences intentionally.  When a binary file is typed to the screen, there is no telling what VT-100 control sequences will be accidentally activated.

Comment: I assumed it had something to do with control sequences, but I can't seem to find any control sequence which changes the representation of Unicode characters, also not in the listing you've linked.

Comment: There are many commands to change character sets.  As [an example](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html), `ESC ( 0` and `ESC ) 0` set "Special Graphics Character Set".  More on control codes to set character sets can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022).  I suspect that it would take quite some digging through font definitions and configuration files to determine which one of these sequences results in your system displaying a lambda as a Japanese character.